# wpbakery Accordion tab auto open when clicking the anchor link

Tags: javascript, anchor, accordion, wpbakery

I'm new to this section. I'm using a wordpress homepage and use wpbakery for creating my content.
My specific problem is that I have an accordion but cannot open it automatically.
That's what I did: created an accordion with different tabs. I wanna use a link like **test.com\accordion#tab2** open the side and automatically the right tab2 of the accordion. Anyone know the code of JS I could use to solve this?

```
    <div class="wpb_column vc_main_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12 typo-default">
        <div class="vc_column-inner ">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                <div class="vc_tta-container" data-vc-action="collapse">
                    <div class="vc_general vc_tta vc_tta-tabs vc_tta-color-grey vc_tta-style-classic vc_tta-shape-rounded vc_tta-spacing-1 vc_tta-tabs-position-top vc_tta-controls-align-left">
                        <div class="vc_tta-tabs-container">
                            <ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
                                <li class="vc_tta-tab vc_active" data-vc-tab="">
                                    <a href="#tabid1" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
                                        <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Tab 1</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
                                    <a href="#tabid2" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
                                        <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Tab 2</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
                                    <a href="#tabid3" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
                                        <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Tab 3</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="vc_tta-panels-container">
                            <div class="vc_tta-panels">
                                <div class="vc_tta-panel vc_active" id="tabid1" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
                                    <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title">
                                            <a href="#tabid1" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container">
                                                <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Tab 1</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="vc_tta-panel-body" style="">
                                        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                                            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                                                <p>text1</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="vc_tta-panel" id="tabid2" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
                                    <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title">
                                            <a href="#tabid2" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container">
                                                <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Tab 2</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="vc_tta-panel-body" style="">
                                        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                                            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                                                <p>text2</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="vc_tta-panel" id="tabid3" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
                                    <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title">
                                            <a href="#tabid3" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container">
                                                <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Tab 3</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="vc_tta-panel-body" style="height: 0px;">
                                        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                                            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                                                <p>text3</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```